# Is there a way to keep a class synchronized between two classes that are using it?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, global

Imagine that there are two jFrames from a view that use methods from a Controller class, the Controller is declared on both jFrames as it follows:

```
public Controller c = new Controller();
```

I need that the information of "c" remains updated and synchronized for both jFrames, so they don't end up having fork results instead of updating or receiving the updated information.

Comment: either inject an instance of your controller class, either make some members static if you need that only the data is in sync...

Comment: @buda-gavril How am I supposed to declare that?, Where do I put the declaration exactly?

Comment: I would advice you to read some books about java or see some tutorials if you don't know what static word means.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to synchronize two instances of a `Controller`, you could create only one instance (e.g., in your `main`), and pass it as an argument to the two JFrames that need to use it.

Comment: Won't work if the Controller class is not threadsafe (likely)

Comment: Actually, I might put a main on the Controller, but I'm not sure if it's gonna work, because I need that the information on the Controller keeps being updated regardless if one frame or the other caused such modification.